# How to pass jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response to a method accepting javax.ws.rs.core.Response

Tags: java, jakarta-migration

I have updated the version of the library

> jakarta.ws.rs-api

from *2.1.6* to *3.0.0*, this has changed the package of Response class from *javax.ws.rs.core* to *jakarta.ws.rs.core*

Now my code uses a library that still accepts *javax.ws.rs.core.Response* objects, this library might take time to switch to the new version of *jakarta.ws.rs-api*.

Any suggestions.